# Is this a good way to force qmake to generate pre-build version info to a header?

Tags: c++, svn, qmake

In the beginning of my `.pro` file, I added:

```
version.commands = "sed -i 's/^.*SW_VERSION.*$$/static const char SW_VERSION[] = \"'"`svnversion .`"'\";/g' ./version.h"
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += version
PRE_TARGETDEPS += version
```

It adds to makefile a single-command target that edits an existing header file: `version.h`, and looks for `SW_VERSION` line, deletes the whole line, and write `static const char SW_VERSION = X;` to that line, where `X` is the svn version of current directory.

Is there a better way to do this?